# How to make a restore image / export ISO to restore later?

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, system-apps, verizon, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

My Samsung galaxy S6 edge+ from Verizon came along with a lot of bloatware I really do not need.

1. First of all it has many pre-installed apps from google which is sadly the case for every android phone I bought till date. These apps can only be disabled under normal circumstances and cannot be uninstalled.
2. Secondly there are apps from Samsung as Galaxy add-ons which I know I will never use.
3. And lastly there are apps from Verizon like Verizon tones etc.

Saddest part is that most of them are redundant like I have two browsers (Chrome and Samsung Internet), two galleries (Google Photos and Samsung Gallery) and the list goes on. They eats up a lot of storage even when I have cleared all their data and disabled them. I decided to root my phone and uninstalled all unnecessary apps. Now everything is good.

But now I want to reset my phone and I know it will wipe out the whole content thing but will restore my phone to its initial state. Initial state means return of all those useless apps too. All settings, launcher preferences, gestures and automation things gone. Do I need to repeat the whole thing from  very beginning to regain current state? So My question is:

**Is'nt there a way that I simply make a restore image or back up my current OS state to somewhere or export an ISO or whatever which I can restore later on to surpass all those steps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the last paragraph of your question first

Since you have rooted the device, flash a custom recovery meant for your device  (Google on XDA for your specific make and model) and take a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup (click on that tag and read the wiki) and restore `/system` to restore the way it is

Next, [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) will not undo the changes you made to the `/system`, it only affects `/data`. Which means apps you uninstalled will not be installed but yes your launcher settings will not survive. That's why it's better to go for Nandroid backup to restore with minimum effort

**Edit** Your device has [official TWRP](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxys6edgeplus.html). Make sure you read the *dm-verity* warning

Comment: But But But....do you want to say that even my default selections and preferences are a part of /system?

Comment: What you say isn't clear to me.  Take an example to clarify what I am saying. You will lose your WiFi password or other settings like keyboard preferences etc, when you reset. These are not restored